# Cannot access docker nginx image on localhost - OSX

Tags: symfony, nginx, docker

I was given a repo containing a PHP Application using Docker/Symfony. I'm able to successfully run `docker-compose up --build` and it looks like everything is running successfully. When I run `docker ps --all` I see everything I'm expecting

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
65d7f22b6b13        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   16 minutes ago      Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:8086->80/tcp   symfony_nginx_1
4fa3c58d1eea        symfony_fpm         "docker-php-entryp..."   16 minutes ago      Up 7 minutes        9000/tcp               symfony_fpm_1
7316d40b1b8c        mysql:5.5           "docker-entrypoint..."   16 minutes ago      Up 7 minutes        3306/tcp               symfony_mysql_1
cac0757e2f6d        redis:latest        "docker-entrypoint..."   16 minutes ago      Up 7 minutes        6379/tcp               symfony_redis_1
```

When I try to access `localhost:8086` on my browser, I get connection refused. I though maybe my local config might be janky and tried this on another machine with the same results. I tried to get the logs of the nginx image by running `docker logs 65d7f22b6b13` but it returns nothing.

Is there something I'm not understanding about docker/nginx and port forwarding that I'm doing incorrectly? Below is my docker config

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8086:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/symfony
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
      - fpm

  fpm:
    build: docker/php-fpm/
    links:
      - redis
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/symfony
      - ./docker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/99-overrides.ini

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.5
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: devdb
      MYSQL_USER: devdb
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: devdb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./backup.sql.gz:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/backup.sql.gz

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
```

I'm on OSX 10.11.6 - Any help appreciated. Symfony and Docker are new to me.

**edit** Below is my nginx config file - I updated `listen` to use `127.0.0.1:8086` but still see it using `0.0.0.0` when I run `docker ps`

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80 default;

    client_max_body_size 108M;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/symfony.access.log;

    root /var/www/symfony/web;

    rewrite ^/index\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }

    # Deny all . files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        send_timeout 1800;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/routemap3_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Statics
        location /(bundles|media) {
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to access 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost. So: http://0.0.0.0:8086/

Comment: just use   listen 80;        remove mention of any server explicitly ... if its still failing then login to nginx container and issue  nginx -t  to view config error message

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in your question:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
65d7f22b6b13        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   16 minutes ago      Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:8086->80/tcp   symfony_nginx_1
```

Now if you read the column `PORTS` carefully you will see `0.0.0.0:8086->80/tcp`, which means that your local loop `0.0.0.0` on port `8086` is mapped to the port `80` of your `ngnix` container, and this with the `tcp` protocol.

So your correct url to access is http://0.0.0.0:8086/

You will also have to change your NGINX config to adapt to that, it should read:

```
listen 0.0.0.0:80;
```

or even better:

```
listen *:80;
```

Comment: I still have the same issue when trying to access it via `0.0.0.0` - I updated my config to use `127.0.0.1` in the `listen` command (see updated post) but it still shows it's running on `0.0.0.0` when I run `docker ps --all`

Comment: That is because docker container has just nothing to do with whatever application it runs, a container is unaware of that. What you say is like saying that my external IP address have to be 127.0.0.1 because I do have a nginx server listening on that IP running somewhere on my machine.

Comment: I'm unclear on what the solution is, sorry if I'm not understanding your comment well. I still can't access it via http://0.0.0.0:8086/